# Fail to incrementColumnValue HBASE with spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, increment

I use Scala to operate on Hbase table

So, I have

```
val myTable = new HTable(hbase_conf, tbl_name)
```

Then, I try to increment a value using this command:

```
myTable.incrementColumnValue(
  "rowkey".getBytes, 
  "data".getBytes,
  "count".getBytes, 
  1)
```

What I get as a result from `hbase shell`

```
hbase(main):047:0> get 'test_marketing', 'rowkey', {COLUMN => 'data:count', VERSIONS =>2}


  COLUMN                        CELL
     data:count             timestamp=1469614608636, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02
     data:count             timestamp=1469614608609, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01
    2 row(s) in 0.0100 seconds
```

How can I get a reasonable value as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `get_counter` command in the `hbase shell`:

Try:

```
get_counter 'test_marketing', 'rowkey', 'data:count'
```

Comment: Thank you. 

Is there a way when I can work with counter like with regular column?
Also I cant normally see this column value when I'm using HUE as HBase UI